# Bernoulli type differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Please, tell me how you could solve the problem
$xy'(x)=a-x+by(x)^2,a>0,b>0$
I tried Bernoulli replacement $z(x)=1/y(x)$, however, this does not lead to success.
On the other hand, Wolfram Mathematica solves it and gives a cumbersome solution:

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x+y%27%5Bx%5D+%3D%3D+a+-+x+%2B+b+y%5Bx%5D%5E2

Comment: It's Riccati's differential equation.

Answer (score 2):

$$y'=\frac{a}{x}-1+\frac{b}{x}y^2$$
The usual method to solve this Riccati equation is the change of function
$$y(x)=-\frac{x}{b}\frac{u'(x)}{u(x)}$$
$$y'=-\frac{1}{b}\frac{u'}{u}-\frac{x}{b}\frac{u''}{u}+\frac{x}{b}\frac{u'^2}{u^2}=\frac{a}{x}-1+\frac{b}{x}\left(-\frac{x}{b}\frac{u'}{u}\right)^2$$
After simplification :
$$-\frac{1}{b}\frac{u'}{u}-\frac{x}{b}\frac{u''}{u}=\frac{a}{x}-1$$
$$x^2u''+xu'+b(a-x)u=0$$
This is an ODE of Bessel kind (on generalized form). To reduce it to the standard form see Eqs.(6-7) in https://mathworld.wolfram.com/BesselDifferentialEquation.html
$$u(x)=c_1\text{I}_{2i\sqrt{ab}}\left(2\sqrt{bx}\right)+c_2\text{I}_{-2i\sqrt{ab}}\left(2\sqrt{bx}\right)$$
$\text{I}_\nu(X)$ is the modified Bessl function of first kind : https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ModifiedBesselFunctionoftheFirstKind.html

Differentiating for $u'(x)$ and $\quad y(x)=-\frac{x}{b}\frac{u'(x)}{u(x)}\quad$ leads to the same cumbersome solution already given by WolfrafAlpha.

If it is for practical application, better use numerical methods of solving instead of analytical.

Comment: Hi Jean ! Long time no see. How are you ?

Comment: JJacquelin: Thanks! But I still have one question. If I take as a solution one of the fundamental solution proposed by you $$u(x)=c_1\text{I}_{2i\sqrt{ab}}\left(2\sqrt{bx}\right)$$ i will get complex $y(x)$. How can this be interpreted?

Comment: There is no spacial interpretation. Bessel functions of real or complex order are both standard functions respectively solutions of modified Bessel differential equation : $$x^2y''+xy'-(x^2+\nu^2)y=0$$ $$x^2y''+xy'-(x^2-\nu^2)y=0$$ In case of complex order $i\nu$ the solution can be real with complex coefficients. $$c_1=a+ib\quad\text{and}\quad c_2=a-ib$$ with $a$ and $b$ real.

Comment: @Claude Leibovici. Hi Claude ! Glad to see that you are here. Warm regards.